# Java - Getting the line number of the text file that a BufferedWriter is writing to

Tags: java, text, numbers, line, bufferedwriter

```
File file = new File (directory + "Test.txt");
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        out.write(in.read() + "This is a line of text.");
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

I am trying to output the following into the text file. Let x represent the line number the BufferedWriter is writing to:

"x. This is a line of text."

But I have no clue as to how to do so and searched for quite a while. Any ideas? THANK YOU!

Comment: Interesting question, I'm also looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in.readLine() method instead of in.read().

```
int linesCount = 0;
String currentLine = "";
while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    linesCount++;
    out.write(currentLine + "\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid doing it like this won't work. I'm having the text saved and loaded every time I open the program, so the linesCount int would be reset every time I opened it again, and it would start back at 0 on say line 43 for example.